# How to efficiently create balanced KD-Trees from a static set of points

Tags: optimization, algorithms, trees, recursive-algorithms

From [Wikipedia, KD-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree):

> Alternative algorithms for building a balanced k-d tree **presort** the data prior to building the tree. They then maintain the order of the presort during tree construction and hence **eliminate the costly step** of finding the median at each level of subdivision. [..] This algorithm presorts n points in **each of k dimensions**

I fail to understand how that is actually done. Consider this example:

Lets say I have 5 points in an array.

```
0 = (4, 7)
1 = (2, 9)
2 = (5, 4)
3 = (3, 6)
4 = (2, 1)
```

I suppose we now want to create 2 sorted arrays, one by X and one by Y ?

```
Sort them by X     Sort them by Y
1 = (2, 9)         4 = (2, 1) 
4 = (2, 1)         2 = (5, 4)
3 = (3, 6)         3 = (3, 6)
0 = (4, 7)         0 = (4, 7)
2 = (5, 4)         1 = (2, 9)
```

We start creating the KD-Tree. Lets split by **X axis**, at the first step. We select the median of the points, `3 = (3, 6)`, so the Left and right trees will like this:

```
Left  (first half)         
1 = (2, 9)   
4 = (2, 1)     

Right  (second half)
0 = (4, 7)      
2 = (5, 4)
```

Now we want to sort the Left and the Right trees by **Y axis**. How are we supposed to make use of the points that we sorted previously by **Y axis** ?

The only solution in my eyes is to re-sort the Left and Right trees respectively, by **Y axis**. What is Wikipedia talking about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make use of pre-sorted lists, the the idea is to use the fact that the median will be located at $i = floor(\frac{N}{2})$, where $N$ is the length of the list you're looking for.

The nice thing about splitting the list is that when we recurse, we can simply use the sub-lists from $[0, i)$ and $[i, N)$ to find the median again.

However, as you noticed, we need to be smart about splitting the two lists in the K-D tree. The general idea is if we pick a point $P = (x_0, y_0)$ to split with, we need to split **both** the $X$-sorted list with respect to $x_0$  **and** the $Y$ sorted list with respect to $x_0$. (We split both according to $x_0$, not one with $x_0$ and one with $y_0$)

In the given example,

```
0 = (4, 7)
1 = (2, 9)
2 = (5, 4)
3 = (3, 6)
4 = (2, 1)
```

When we split with the point `4 = (2, 1)`, the

$X$ list splits as: (it splits at $x_0 = 2$)

```
1 = (2, 9)       
4 = (2, 1)
----------  
3 = (3, 6)
0 = (4, 7) 
2 = (5, 4)
```

Clearly, the two sub-lists are still sorted by $x$

the $Y$ list splits at $x_0 = 2$

```
4 = (2, 1) 
1 = (2, 9)
----------
2 = (5, 4)
3 = (3, 6)
0 = (4, 7)
```

Notice that the two subsections of the $Y$ are *still sorted* with respect to the y coordinate, but they were *split* along the x coordinate.

Implementing this is exactly like implementing the reverse of the `merge` operation from merge sort.

Now that you have the $X$ and $Y$ sublists for the recursion, you can continue building the K-D tree.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you split Y according to x_0 = 2?
How did (2,9) "climbed" to form the partition with (2, 1)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing a couple of things here:

1. When you split along an axis, you take a plane *perpendicular* to that axis and choose points that are "in front of" and "behind" this plane. While you're correct in saying that when you divide along the X axis you can simply look at the $x_0$ from the point $P(x_0, y_0)$, in general, you would like to actually create the equation of a plane and check which side the point is to the plane. [Example - point position relative to plane](http://www.ixaarii.com/programming/papers/point-position-relative-to-a-plane/)
2. You split points into buckets in a step-by-step process, *one plane at a time*. You're trying to do both X and Y at the same time - don't. Do it one at a time, building up one level of the tree for one plane.

So, in your case, first take

```
0 = (4, 7)
1 = (2, 9)
2 = (5, 4)
3 = (3, 6)
4 = (2, 1)
```

Now, split along `4 = (2, 1)` as you suggested, giving

```
Left of X = 2         
   1 = (2, 9)   
   3 = (3, 6)     
Right of X = 2
   0 = (4, 7)      
   2 = (5, 4)
```

Now that you have the left and right halves, we need to find a division along the Y axis for both the X axis halves (the divisions can be the same, or they can be different for the left and right subtrees of the X axis)

For the left subtree

```
1 = (2, 9)   
3 = (3, 6)
```

We could pick the median of the Y $y_0 = 6$ from $(3, 6)$

Similarly, for the right subtree

```
0 = (4, 7)      
2 = (5, 4)
```

We pick the median of Y being $y_0 = 4$ from $(5, 4)$

Hence, the resulting tree will be:

```
Left of X = 2
    Left of Y = 6
        3 = (3, 6)     
    Right of Y = 6
        1 = (2, 9)   

Right of X = 2
    Left of Y = 4
        2 = (5, 4)
    Right of Y = 4
        0 = (4, 7)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `let's say you split at Y=6` how did you compute that ?

Comment: Siddharth :  just to say that [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) are [BSP trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) where all the hyperplanes are parallel or perpendicular to the axis  (hence at each node the (child) points are splitted with respect to one coordinate)

Comment: Your result is definitely not right. If you chose element `3` to split in axis Y, then that element would become the node itself and it would have NULL on its left and the element `1` on its right. The problem is that in order to choose between elements `3` and `1`, you have to sort them by Y and pick the middle one. And to do that, the previous array of sorted points by Y wouldn't help, because now we want to sort `3` and `1`, not ALL elements.

Comment: @Shiro - yes, you're right. You need to find the median _per subtree_. Sorry I screwed up. I'll edit my post to reflect the changes

Comment: The point of the question is `how to find the median efficiently` and what does wikipedia imply

Comment: The point is that usually, you need to find the median of the entire list, but here, the effort of finding the median reduces by half each time.

Comment: Look at the wikipedia quote of my question

Comment: Also, most of the time, you do not use the median - there are better algorithms / heuristics to do this. [Look at this stackOverflow discussion for a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632951/kdtree-splitting)

Comment: What do you mean ? I have a set of coordinates and I want to create a KDTree with them. I need to use median. Take a look at the wikipedia quote... `presorts n points in each of k dimensions`. Your answer doesn't really answer my question. I am familiar with KDTrees. You mention `the effort of finding the median reduces by half each time`. That is what I am using right now. Wikipedia says that we can make it more effecient. And this is why I posted this question, asking "how?"

Comment: Ah, I see, I was mis understanding your question then. If you have a pre-sorted list, then the median is guaranteed to be present at $floor(n/2)$ where n is the length of your array. Simply "slice" the array each time you make a subdivision, and pass the smaller (but still sorted) lists to your recursive call. Since the lists are still sorted, you can continue to find the median with $floor(n/2)$, but this time only considering the sliced subsection of the pre-sorted array

Comment: That is not right. We first split by X. We get Left and Right. The right has elements `0` and `2`. Lets try and split that Right by Y. The median of Right  *by Y* is element `2`. Is element `2` on the bottom half of our pre-calculated sorted list by Y ? Nope. It is the 2nd element. It does not work like that. I can't understand how to make use of the `pre-sorted` list. It seems like the only way is to calculate the median every single time. Of course list is half size each time, but wikipedia says we can use pre-calculated lists. Question still stands... "how?"

Comment: No, see, when you split the point with $(x_0, y_0)$, you need to split __both__ the $X$ list and the $Y$ list. You split the $x$ list according to $x_0$ and the $Y$ list according to $y_0$. Having it pre-sorted means that you don't need to sort again

Comment: I think you are correct. I will take some time to think about what you just said.

Comment: cool :) do you want me to write a separate answer for this?

Comment: If you are positive it is correct, sure. Please do so. Right now I am testing what you said in various examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39102/discussion-between-shiro-and-siddharth-bhat).

Comment: Also, here, when you are splitting along 4 = (2, 1) you repeat the illogicality from the original question by repeating that (3, 6) is *left* from X = 2. It is not.